# How to find the language of a Tweet using Tweepy?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets

I gave a stream of Tweets that I filter based on certain criteria. I do not wish to use the language criteria during streaming itself. Rather, I wish to know the language of such filtered tweets.

I'm using Tweepy for streaming. Kindly suggest to me a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Status`/[Tweet objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) have a `lang` attribute. Note though, that it is *nullable*, meaning it could be `None`:

> When present, indicates a [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) language identifier corresponding to the machine-detected language of the Tweet text, or `und` if no language could be detected.